# sim900 only responds to AT commands when empty sketch is uploaded

Tags: arduino, sim900

I am using a gsm sim900 shield connected to an Arduino uno for my project. The Sim900 only responds to AT commands when I upload an empty sketch to the Arduino. If I put any AT command code in the sketch, the sim900 just echoes the AT commands without giving any response. What could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to post a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example of your code in a question.

Comment: The response from the GSM module for commands are actually just echoes ( for initialization commands) .And if you could tell which all commands you tried then only can help you.If you want some codes then please tell your needs.

Answer (score 0):

with the information you gave I can throw a guess and say that you don't write at the end of the AT command "\r\n".